# WinForm app: Cannot set default values of a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

I have created a Windows Forms Application and inserted a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn as the first column of the grid, but I have been unsuccessful in setting the default value to "checked".  I have tried to set it both in a loop after I insert the column and in the DefaultValuesNeeded event of the gridview.  Is there an easier way to do this, or is there something I'm missing?

My code is as follows:

```
private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        BAFarmer baobj = new BAFarmer();
        gvFarmers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gvFarmers.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        gvFarmers.DataSource = baobj.GetAllFarmersCol();
        gvFarmers.Enabled = true;
        gvFarmers.ReadOnly = false;

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkColumn.Name = "Include";
        checkColumn.ValueType = typeof(Boolean);
        checkColumn.HeaderText = "Include";
        checkColumn.Width = 50;
        checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
        checkColumn.ThreeState = false;
        checkColumn.TrueValue = true;
        checkColumn.FalseValue = false;


        gvFarmers.Columns.Insert(0, checkColumn);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvFarmers.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[checkColumn.Name].Value = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding code to the form load event that loops through the check boxes and sets them at that point.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvFarmers.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["Select"];
    chk.Value = true;
}
```